# Jupyter Lab 3.0 の起動ブラウザを変更しても反映されない

Tags: jupyter-lab

Anaconda Navigator (anaconda3 )から Jupyter Lab (3.0.16) を起動するブラウザを、現状の Microsoft Edge から Google Chrome に変更したく、以下のサイトを参考にしながら作業を実施しましたが、依然起動は Microsoft Edge で起動してしまいす。

**参照したサイト:**

[JupyterLab3.0の起動ブラウザを指定する方法](https://qiita.com/matsxxx/items/10c93edab12a93604aab)

▲サイトでの設定変更手順を下記に要約。

1. jupyter labでconfigファイルを作成します。

   ```
   jupyter lab --generate-config
   ```
2. 実行すると `/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py` が作成されます。
3. `/.jupyter/jupyter_lab_config.py` 内のコメントアウトを外し、ブラウザexeのパスを記入して、保存します。
4. そうすると、Jupyter Lab での起動ブラウザを指定することができます。

以上の手順で行いましたが、依然 Microsoft Edge で起動してしまいます。

▲その他

自身での解決として「ジュピターラボ ブラウザ 変更」などのキーワードで検索して参考サイトを探しましたがダメでした。ご教授お願いします。

下記に自身が行ったブラウザexeのパス

```
625　c.ServerApp.browser = '"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"' %s
```

Comment: 画像を見ますと、行頭に `#` が入ったままになっている様に見えます。

Comment: "#"削除すると…波線が表示されますが…

Comment: 「コメントアウトを外し」なのにコメントアウトのまま？
コメントになってるのなら動かなくて当然ですが？

Comment: 初学者にて、「コメントアウトを外し」とは、上記添付画像を元に、具体的にご教授お願いします。

Comment: c.ServerApp.browser = '"C:\\Program iles\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"' %sで、c.下に波線　%sのs下に波線表示

Comment: 修正しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こんな風に`.exe"' %s`文字列の最後を示す後ろのシングルクォーテーションが`%s`の前に来ているように見えます。単にそれを行末に移動して`.exe" %s'`にすれば良いのでは？ あるいは参照記事だと`.exe`と`"`の間にも `\ `が入っているので、`.exe\" %s'`にするのかもしれませんが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私も途中で気づき%sを'内に入れました。又、ご指摘の通り参考サイトは”\"なので同じく表記しました。上記にも書きましたが、依然cの波線が消えません。「コメントアウトを外し」とは、＃削除の理解でいいのでしょうか？

Comment: `c.`下に波線が残るのは、`jupyter_lab_config.py`がスクリプトとして成立する完結したプログラムではなく、言わば`.ini`ファイルのようなもので設定情報だけが置かれているためでしょう。それ自身は問題無いと思われます。こちらで`(base)`環境で試してみたところでは問題無くブラウザが切り替わります。何らかの環境や情報の整合性が取れていないのでしょう。根気よく間違いを探すか、一時的にシステムのデフォルトブラウザを変更してみるとか試してみてください。コメントについては例えば`Python コメントアウト`とかで検索すると [Pythonのコメント、コメントアウトの書き方](https://note.nkmk.me/python-comment/), [［Python入門］コメント](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1904/26/news026.html) といった記事が見つかります。色々と入門コース記事などありますので、適当なもので基本的な知識を一通り覚えておいた方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 貴重なご助言、ありがとうございます。一度Anaconda Navigator (anaconda3 )削除再インストールしてみます。

Comment: 初学者だからとか初学者でないとか関係なく,(この質問の場合)どういう手順で どのステップまで進みどこで躓いている,このような記述があるがどういう意味かわからない … など 記すべきところを, 記していないのは問題です。
いずれコメントのやり取りで話に上がり補完, という流れがあったにせよ, (最初から)質問に状況を書かなくていいということはありません。

[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘を忘れないようにします。

Answer (score -1):

自身のPC起動時のブラウザを変更することにより、解決しました。