# 'jupyter_lab_config.py' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、 操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

Tags: anaconda3, jupyter-lab

[Jupyter Labのブラウザをデフォルトから変更](http://izmmr.blog.jp/archives/10215436.html) のページを参照して、生成された `.py` ファイルを Anaconda Prompt(anaconda3) で実行した所、下記のエラーが表示されました。

```
'jupyter_lab_config.py' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

エラー解決の為、

- 他のコマンドプロンプトで試みましたが…ダメ。
- エラーを検索して…”AzureADモジュールをインストールする”とありましたが…訳分からなくなりました。
  一応、`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module MSOnline` を実行しましたが…ダメでした。

ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anacondaやjupyterをインストールしただけでは、ファイル拡張子の関連付けが登録されないのでしょう。

[Windows のファイル拡張子の関連付け](https://qiita.com/TsuneoNakanishi/items/5f0248c82bf073cf2868)

例はPythonではないがGUIで操作する方法
[Windows 10 ファイルの関連付けと既定のプログラムを変更する](https://www.tipsfound.com/windows10/11003)

そのため、Anaconda Prompt(anaconda3)からの実行であっても、Pythonスクリプトのファイル名`jupyter_lab_config.py`だけでは実行できません。

**ファイルの存在するディレクトリまで移動して`python jupyter_lab_config.py`とするか、パラメータとしてスクリプトファイルを指定するのに相対または絶対パスを入力する必要があります。**

上記参考記事の手順でPythonスクリプトのファイル名だけで実行出来るようになりますが、単に登録しただけではAnaconda Prompt(anaconda3)でなくても実行出来てしまうし、その時はPythonの他のディレクトリがPATHに登録されていないので正しく動かない場合があります。

---

参考：
AnacondaではないオリジナルのPythonインストーラでPythonと共にPython Launcherもインストールすると、PATHにPythonのディレクトリを追加していなくてもファイル拡張子の関連付けを登録してくれて、スクリプトファイル名だけ入力するだけで実行出来るようになります。
ただし、その時実行されるのはAnacondaのPythonではなく、オリジナルのPythonインストーラでインストールしたPythonですが。

---

ちなみに`jupyter_lab_config.py`自身は @cubick さんの回答や、私が以前の質問 [Jupyter Lab 3.0 の起動ブラウザを変更しても反映されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/81164/26370) のコメントに書いたように、jupyter labの設定情報のファイルなので、プログラムとして完結したものではありません。

また、Windows上で作成されると`encoding`が`shift_jis`になっているようです。

そうした2つの要因で`jupyter_lab_config.py`自身をファイル名だけで実行出来るようになっても、エラーになるだけで意味はありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。前回ご助言を参考にWindows10再セットアップしました。アナコンダ３も新たにインストールしました。ジュピターラボ初起動時、Google Chromeを設定して、無事ジュピターラボをGoogle Chromeで起動になりました。その後、(base) C:\Users\genki>pip install --upgrade jupyterlabした後、起動すると…マイクロソフトEdgeでの起動になりました。で、前回同様、同じサイトを参照しての作業となりましたが、その際、kunifさんの前回のご助言内容に自身の環境では問題なくとありました中で(base)とあったので、まねて今回はアナコンダ３プロンプトで試した結果…でした。ちなみにファイルをクリックしVSCodeきどうされ、参照通り、してみましたが、Edgeでの起動でした。

Comment: 何か本当にやりたい事と質問内容が少し違う [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370) の感じですね。その辺の何かが違うなら、本当にやりたいけれど行き詰まっていることを対象に新たな質問を立ててください。あるいは前回の続きならば前回の質問に追記してみてください。それから少し改善されているようですが Anaconda では pip はどうしようもない場合以外は使わない方が良いと思われます。 [condaとpip：混ぜるな危険](https://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/11/142347), [condaとpip：ver. 2020](https://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/10/24/conda%E3%81%A8pip:_ver__2020)

Comment: 貴重なご意見、ありがとうございます。以後の指針とします。

Answer (score 0):

生成された jupyter_lab_config.py はあくまで設定ファイルであり、プロンプトから実行しようとすること自体が間違いだと思います。